# Как работают эти 2 примера кода?

Tags: javascript

Как, почему этот код возвращает именно сумму элементов подмассива, а не сумму всех элементов или нуль?Я так понимаю, что в partialSum добавляются все элементы массива

```
    function getMaxSubSum(arr) {


let maxSum = 0;
  let partialSum = 0;

  for (let item of arr) { // for each item of arr
    partialSum += item; // add it to partialSum
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, partialSum); // remember the maximum
    if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0; // zero if negative
  }

  return maxSum;
}

alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3, -9]) ); // 5
alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3, -9, 11]) ); // 11
alert( getMaxSubSum([-2, -1, 1, 2]) ); // 3
alert( getMaxSubSum([100, -9, 2, -3, 5]) ); // 100
alert( getMaxSubSum([1, 2, 3]) ); // 6
alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, -2, -3]) ); // 0
```

А этот пример это вообще бред... Зачем этот цикл с j внутри i?Что-бы не присвоить sumFixedStart значение 0 при новой итерации? Почему тогда нельзя было просто за пределами цикла присвоить этой переменной 0?

```
function getMaxSubSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0; // if we take no elements, zero will be returned

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let sumFixedStart = 0;
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      sumFixedStart += arr[j];
      maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, sumFixedStart);
    }
  }

  return maxSum;
}

alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3, -9]) ); // 5
alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3, -9, 11]) ); // 11
alert( getMaxSubSum([-2, -1, 1, 2]) ); // 3
alert( getMaxSubSum([1, 2, 3]) ); // 6
alert( getMaxSubSum([100, -9, 2, -3, 5]) ); // 100
```

Comment: И что не так? Функция находит максимально возможное значение. Она не может вернуть сумму всех элементов, т.к. строка " maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, partialSum);" находит большее значение из 2. Это может быть 1 число, а может быть сумма 2 элементов

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко смотри, челик.Math.max выдаёт нам либо maxSum, который на тот момент равен нулю - либо partialSum, который сумма всех элементов масссива, я это так понимаю

Comment: как бы maxSum постоянно меняется. Равен 0 только вначале

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы чётко понимать что происходит, лучше всего воспользоваться дебаггером.

Если пока не умеете, можете просто залогировать процесс вычислений:

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
function getMaxSubSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0; // if we take no elements, zero will be returned

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let sumFixedStart = 0;
    pre.textContent += `Try partial sums starting from index ${i} (${arr[i]})\n`;
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      sumFixedStart += arr[j];
      pre.textContent += `\tMath.max(${maxSum}, ${arr.slice(i, j+1).join('+')}=${sumFixedStart}) = ${Math.max(maxSum, sumFixedStart)}\n`;
      maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, sumFixedStart);
    }
  }

  return maxSum;
}
;[
  [-1, 2, 3, -9],
  [-1, 2, 3, -9, 11],
  [-2, -1, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [100, -9, 2, -3, 5],
].forEach(testCase => {
  pre.textContent += `Solve case: ${JSON.stringify(testCase)}\n`;
  let res = getMaxSubSum(testCase);
  pre.textContent += `Result is ${res}\n--\n`;
});
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```